# Project build failed

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I was trying to run my react native project on android studio emulator but when I build it this error appears:

> Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'.
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\COURSES\ReactNative-ThePracticalGuide\
>   myFirstApp\android\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-conf
>   ig.json

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it is really simple

```
cd android
gradlew clean
cd..
npm run android
```